# Navbar with multiple dropdowns: How to DRY?

Tags: javascript, html, css

As per the title, I'm making a navbar with multiple dropdowns. The idea is to open the dropdowns menus onmouseover.

I have written the following functions:

```
function toggleStudies() {document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content')[0].classList.toggle("show")}
function toggleUtils() {document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content')[1].classList.toggle("show")}
```

... Up to `('dropdown-content')[4]`.

Besides, I have also had to put the function twice on each `div`, like this:

```
    <div class="dropdown" onmouseout="toggleStudies()" onmouseover="toggleStudies()" >
```

Whereas it should display, upon mouseover, the hidden `div`, which is `dropdown-content`, and hide it back on mouseout which is organized like this:

```
<div class="dropdown" onmouseout="toggleStudies()" onmouseover="toggleStudies()" >
        <button class="dropbtn" >Studies</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">X</a>
            <a href="#">Y</a>
            <a href="#">W</a>
            <a href="#">Z</a>
        </div>
```

Which repeats another four times.

It IS working like this. However, what I want is to make it DRYer.

I have thought about a loop that would `addEventListener` onmouseover and onmouseout to all the `<div class="dropdown">"` elements, but I couldn't figure a function that could be passed so that it would substitute the previous five `function toggle()`.

How can it be done?

Comment: add hover listener to the `a` tag, then in the call back you can access the one that is hovered with `this`

Answer (score 1):

Would suggest using forEach() for this.

```
var dropdown = querySelectorAll(".dropdown");
dropdown.forEach(function(){
    this.addEventListener(onmouseout, toggleStudies());
    this.addEventListener(onmousein, toggleStudies());
});
```

This should get you started

Thanks,
Ashish